# Ограничение размера области экрана для меню

Tags: java, android, оформление

В приложении есть такое навигационное меню:
[image: Меню]

И на разных телефонах оно занимает разную часть экрана, как сделать чтоб при любом разрешении это меню было в самом низу, и чтоб не закрывало элементы которые идут выше него . Заранее спасибо !

разметка:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.ChatListActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/new_layout_relative"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"> </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Это экран с меню, а остальные экраны в виде фрагментов . Пример:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewChat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Отображается так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: покажите разметку где используется данное меню

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот например есть разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".screens.HomeScreen">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentContainerT"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation_t"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp" />


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_t"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:itemBackground="@color/bottom_nav_color"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selected_text"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selected_text"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:menu="@menu/main_bottom_nav_menu" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

здесь менюшка всегда висит внизу экрана и никуда не девается на любых устроствах. И вообще у вас есть строка:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

которая должна решать вашу проблему. Попробуйте убрать

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

может конфликтует.

Comment: Попробовал, всё равно на маленьком экране отображается не так, пример добавил в основной вопрос.

Comment: приподнимите макет фрагмента на 56dp, того который на скрине

Comment: Как мне правильно это сделать? если я меняю значение в  android:layout_height="match_parent" , то это как то не так работает .

Comment: нет, не нужно менять высоту, добавьте отступ - `android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"` в макете фрагмента

Comment: Спасибо вы очень помогли